# Do we need the "search" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [search](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) has no definition.

We have other tags [text-search](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-search) and [search-engine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine).

Do we really need [search](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search)?

if so, what is its definition?

Comment: I'm not sure if [tag:text-search] and [tag:search-engine] are any better, and anyway they don't encompass all search-related topics. Why would we get rid of [tag:search]? What tags would we create instead?

Comment: Then can we define  when the tag "search" should be used?

Comment: I think `search` might need a tag-wiki. `text-search` is intuitive, but `search` might even erraneously be used as "I'm looking for a software that …" :) Currently it seems most of its questions are about file-search. Btw: I'm having my doubts about the `search-engine` tag: there are several questions looking for "something like Google" (my simplification), which IMHO is outside of our scope. I keep my fingers out of those as I never got the difference what kind of "service" is on-topic here :)